# Can I use PHP in_array with needle as array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to give in_array it's needle as an array? For example:

```
$needle = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$haystack = array(5,6,7,8,9);

if(in_array($needle,$haystack)){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well what should it return when it just finds 1 needle? TRUE/FALSE? Just write your own little function and loop through the needles and search for them in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) Example #3 for `in_array()` with an array as needle:

```
<?php
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a)) {
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}

if (in_array(array('f', 'i'), $a)) {
    echo "'fi' was found\n";
}

if (in_array('o', $a)) {
    echo "'o' was found\n";
}
?>
```

The real question is whether it will give you whatever results you may expect.

Answer (score 0):

What is the result are you looking for TRUE / FALSE?  You can use one of these functions:

To find the elements in both arrays:

```
array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Or to find the differences:

```
array_diff($array1, $array2);
```